# Is it secure enough use an Ed25519 expanded secret key which converted from a sr25519 key

Tags: polkadot-js, wallet, security, sr25519, ed25519

I am developing a wallet using Rust and I want it to be compatible with `polkadot-js` import/export functionality. I know that `polkadot-js` uses the `ed25519` extended mode for `sr25519` private keys. So, I use `SecretKey::from_ed25519_bytes` to obtain the private key. However, when I export it again, it returns a different value. The example value is as follows:

```
value imported: "0x476c696365202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020d172a74cda4c865912c32ba0a80a57ae69abae410e5ccb59dee84e2f4432db4f";
value exported: "0x406c696365202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020d172a74cda4c865912c32ba0a80a57ae69abae410e5ccb59dee84e2f4432db4f
```

I understand that this change occurs because when converting from `ed25519` to `sr25519` form, it divides by a cofactor, and when converting back, it multiplies by a cofactor and applies masking.
I would like to know if this usage method is secure enough and if it could potentially result in collisions between some users' private keys.

Comment: Note: `Privakey != Secretkey`

Comment: Can you talk more about that? I see that in the specific implementation, schnorrkel's `Keypair` just uses SecretKey object as the private key without further conversion.